# Wiremock dependency not importing classes

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependencies, wiremock, mockserver

I am trying to use Wiremock for my spring api.
I am using Java 17.

I am using this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiremock-standalone</artifactId>
    <version>2.27.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am trying to import the WireMockServer class

I have tried saving the pom.xml, cleaning and startig the project, updating the project, but it still wont import the class i want or anything else from the import, just keeps telling me i need to make the class

the code in my MockServerConfig.java class is

```
public class MockServerConfig extends WireMockServer {


}
```

Comment: Is this class inside the tests or inside your program?

Comment: @JFabianMeier inside the program

Comment: This is a very old version. Ideally I'd suggest using 3.0.0-beta-7, or failing that 2.35.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dependency with `<scope>test</scope>` can only be used in tests. Remove the scope to use it elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This fixed my issues but has lead me to wondering, do you recommend i use wiremocks in the program or inside the tests?